# Why does the while loop not go through the loop, it stops after the first 3 inputs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm trying to get this program to calculate how much these movies will cost the customer, but the while loop only asks the first three questions it never prints the total, the tax or anything else. Please help me solve this problem!

```
def checkout():
    The_Bourne_Identity = 1
    Harry_Potter = 2
    Holy_Cross = 3
    Arrival = 4
    Hidden = 5

    price_of_movie = 0
    price_of_movie2 = 0
    price_of_movie3 = 0
    price_of_movie4 = 0
    price_of_movie5 = 0

    ans = 0
    response = 'y'

    while response == 'y':
        ans = int(input('What movie do you have?'))
        q1 = int(input('How many of these do you have'))
        response =input('Do you have a different movie?: type y for yes: ')
        if ans == The_Bourne_Identity:
            price_of_movie = 9.99 * q1  
            return price_of_movie
        elif ans == Harry_Potter:
            price_of_movie2 = 15.99 * q1
            return price_of_movie2   

        elif ans == Holy_Cross:
            price_of_movie3 = 4.75 * q1
            return price_of_movie3
        elif ans == Arrival:
            price_of_movie4 = 24.99 * q1
            return price_of_movie4 

        elif ans == Hidden:
            price_of_movie4 = 29.98 * q1
            return price_of_movie5



    movie_total_price =  price_of_movie + price_of_movie2 + price_of_movie3 + price_of_movie4 + price_of_movie5

    movie_tax = movie_total_price * .07
    total_cost = movie_tax + movie_total_price

    print("Your movies cost,", movie_total_price)
    print("Your tax will be,", movie_tax)
    print("Your total cost,", total_cost)


def main():
    checkout()
main()
```

when I run it just does the first 3 questions and stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `return`ing midway. The rest codes in the method will not be executed. Instead of `return` just use `movie_total_price` for total-cost and add up. Change your method like this (could be refactored a LOT more):

```
def checkout():
    The_Bourne_Identity = 1
    Harry_Potter = 2
    Holy_Cross = 3
    Arrival = 4
    Hidden = 5

    price_of_movie = 0
    price_of_movie2 = 0
    price_of_movie3 = 0
    price_of_movie4 = 0
    price_of_movie5 = 0
    movie_total_price = 0
    ans = 0
    response = 'y'

    while response == 'y':
        ans = int(input('What movie do you have?'))
        q1 = int(input('How many of these do you have'))
        response =input('Do you have a different movie?: type y for yes: ')

        if ans == The_Bourne_Identity:
            movie_total_price += 9.99 * q1              
        elif ans == Harry_Potter:
            movie_total_price += 15.99 * q1
        elif ans == Holy_Cross:
            movie_total_price += 4.75 * q1            
        elif ans == Arrival:
            movie_total_price += 24.99 * q1
        elif ans == Hidden:
            movie_total_price += 29.98 * q1


    movie_tax = movie_total_price * .07
    total_cost = movie_tax + movie_total_price

    print("Your movies cost,", movie_total_price)
    print("Your tax will be,", movie_tax)
    print("Your total cost,", total_cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

You return from the checkout function if any of the conditions is True. If there isn't a reason to do so, comment out the return statements and you should see the remaining logs.